# Discord bot not responding or listening to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've just revisited some old discord bot code and quite obviously it does not work.
The code below is a lot larger, but even when I shrink it down to importing modules, setting a client prefix, on_ready(), and finally a client.command(), the bot just wont listen or respond.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import  commands, tasks
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')

@client.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    print('listening')
    await ctx.send('Pong! '+str(round(client.latency * 1000))+'ms')

client.run(my token)
```

Now, here I am listening for '!! ping', or '!!ping' (ive tried typing both)
If the bot is listening to this command, it should atleast print out `listening` into my terminal. If that is so, it should send a message to my discord channel.

However, neither of these are happening.

Note: An on ready function as shown below prints `Bot is ready`. Additonally, in discord I can see the bot is online.

```
#Connect Bot
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Bot is ready')
```

Comment: You are missing the message_content intent. Check the link provided above

Answer (score 3):

You could also try downgrading your Discord py version.

First uninstall discord py
pip uninstall discord.py

Then Install this version of discord.py
pip install discord.py==1.7.2

This version does not include the intents which means your code should work without them

Answer (score 0):

Enable intents to your code by doing this and that should fix your issue.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", intents=intents)
```

Make sure to enable intents on your discord dev portal, [this](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/_images/discord_privileged_intents.png) will show you how.

Comment: He needs the `message_content` intent, not `members`

Answer (score -1):

client in my opinion is very limited and messy,
can you try switching it to bot?

Your code:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')
```

New code

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

also if you updated it to 2.0 you also need intents

Comment: You just changed a variable name, that doesn't make any difference at all.... And he's _already using ``commands.Bot`` instead of a ``discord.Client``_..........